# Zurb Foundation - Mobile navigation not opening in second tier hierarchy pages

Tags: navigation, responsiveness, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using the Zurb Foundation 6 framework on this website http://hlb-mann-judd.businesscatalyst.com. Everything is good apart from the mobile navigation not opening for pages that are in a second tier heirarchy. Here's a link where the problem occurs http://hlb-mann-judd.businesscatalyst.com/software/myob  The mobile nav bars appear but they don't function anymore

Nothing is different on these pages apart from the fact that they have a second tier path name and I've checked that the second tier pages have the correct path name for all relevant files so it's not that that's causing the problem (though I figure it has something to do with it somehow). If anybody can advise me as to what is required to fix this I'd appreciate it heaps.

Here's the relevant code:

```
 <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style-custom.css" />      

</head>

<body>
    <div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
        <div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner">
            <!--Mobile Navigation-->
            <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvasLeft" data-off-canvas data-position="left">
                <button class="close-button" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <ul class="mobile-ofc vertical menu">
                    <!--MOBILE NAVIGATION LINKS HERE   -->    
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--end Mobile Navigation-->


            <header class="inner-header-bg">

                <div class="off-canvas-content">
                    <!-- Info Banner For Announcements or Links -->
                    <a href="/index.html" id="notice">
                        <div class="info">
                            <img src="/_assets/img/hlb-mann-judd-logo-mobile.png" alt="logo" />
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- desktop nav-->
                        <nav class="marketing-topbar show-for-medium">                               
                            <div class="desktopMenuWrap">
                                <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu data-click-open="false">                                        
                                    <!--DESKTOP NAVIGATION LINKS HERE    -->                                    
                                </ul>                                    
                            </div>                                
                        </nav>
                        <!-- end desktop nav-->
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="title-bar hide-for-medium">
                        <div class="title-bar-left">
                            <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-open="offCanvasLeft"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <!-- end header -->



        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/mobileApp.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scroll/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scroll/jquery.smoothAnchors.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: There is an error in the JS console on the pages where this problem occurs: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

Comment: Thanks Colin! I'll see if I can make sense of it.